# Loading .obj in OpenGL in C

Tags: c, opengl, import, .obj, wavefront

I am relatively new to OpenGL and am using it for a class that requires me to use it with C (no C++). I would like to use .obj files in my code, but do not know how to import them. I have found many importers online for C++, but must use C. Can anyone direct me to an importer or give me the basics on how to write my own/handle and import .obj files into my program. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of WaveFront OBJ loader in C - http://kixor.net/dev/objloader/

Comment: Thank you! A lot more help than people just down voting my question